# ie8 Anchor Link issue

Tags: internet-explorer-8, anchor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="testing.html">Testing</a>
</body>
</html>
```

in ie8 i was not able to navigate to that page.. anchor click is not working...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), questions should be *questions*. What's the question? Also: I've fixed the code formatting in the question for you. Please take a moment to read the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the Ask a Question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. (There's also a preview box shown under the Ask a Question box where you can preview your question.)

Comment: Are you sure testing.html exists? In the same directory as this file?

Answer (score 1):

An anchor link needs to have somewhere to go, for example, `<a name="foo"></a>` the anchor link would be `<a href="#foo"></a>`